# How to send an event object to handler?

Tags: javascript

I'm iterating an array of inputs, and adding an eventhandler to "oninput" event:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');                                                                                          
Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {                                                    
                          input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
});
```

Event handler:

```
function _onInputEvent(e) {
}
```

In e.target property - i'm getting `"input.form-control"` as expected.

I've changed the above a little to:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');                                                                                          
    Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {                                                    
                              input.oninput = _onInputEvent(event);
    });
```

But now in e.target property (on the event handler) - i'm getting `"document"` object.

Why is that ? and what should I pass in order to get `"input.form-control"` in e.target property ?

Comment: Your first implementation is correct and associating event handlers with element, However In the second implementation, you are invoking the function

Comment: @Satpal I need to add parameters, so I have to add arguments. How can I implement it with arguments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error as you are invoking when you use `_onInputEvent(event)` and binding the value returned by function to `oninput` event handler.

You can use anonymous function to bind event.

*script*

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');                                                                                          
Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {                                                    
      input.oninput = function(event){
            _onInputEvent(event, someParameters);
      }                           
});
```